# Checking if current site is forum

Tags: php, html, wordpress, bbpress

I'm using `wordpress` and `bbPress` to write a forum. I have to display an element on this site before header, but only when current site is forum. How can I check if this site is forum ?

Comment: What is your bbPress url?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `is_bbpress()` and check if page use bbpress.
Example

```
if ( class_exists('bbPress') ) {
     if ( bbp_is_forum_archive() ) {

            echo 'You are on the Support Forums Archives. These are all the forums.';

     }
}
```